# Android: custom marker cluster

Tags: android, maps, markers, personalization

Hello i have to implement  custom markers like the markers in the picture here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cwsq8hpkmeypo4b/AndroidMap.png?dl=0
someone can suggest me some tutorial or  reference to follow thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/), you can use `setIcon()` method in Marker class.

Read the documentation on [how to customize the marker image](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image)

Comment: I read the doc but i didn't understand how can i create the array of images attached to each marker as in my picture i have to use canvas? thx

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start if you are looking to implement clustering with custom cluster icons is the Google Maps Android API Utility.

Here's a good guide on how to get started with it:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

Good Luck!